# Split 1D array into 2D blocks without reshaping or increasing step size

Tags: python

Assume there is an image (5x5):

```
      [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

I am given a flattened grayscale array of the image, like:

```
[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

I need to split it into blocks, given a block size of 3 and knowing the width and height (5x5) without using array slicing, reshaping, or having more than 1 step size because the code will be implemented also in C later:

```
[[0,  1,  2, 5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 12], 
[3,  4, 8,  9, 13, 14], 
[15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22], 
[18, 19, 23, 24]]
```

I have so far made the following, which splits based on the window size, but not the width and the height

```
WIDTH = 5
HEIGHT = 5
windowsize = 3

image = np.arange(0, WIDTH*HEIGHT)

arrays = []
for _ in range(0, (WIDTH*HEIGHT)//windowsize+windowsize):
    arrays.append([])

for i in range(0, len(image)):
    print ("append", image[i], "to index", (i // windowsize))

    arrays[i // windowsize].append(image[i])

print (arrays)
```

Comment: No explanation on how the expected output is obtained.

Comment: @BillHuang what do you mean? It is described in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as non-Pythonic as can be but it should be fairly easy to convert to C:

```
windowSize = 3
WIDTH      = 5
HEIGHT     = 5

#flattened...
image = list(range(WIDTH*HEIGHT))

arrays = []

for v in range(0,HEIGHT,windowSize):
    for h in range(0,WIDTH,windowSize):
        block = []
        for r in range(v,min(v+windowSize,WIDTH)):
            for c in range(h,min(h+windowSize,HEIGHT)):
                block.append(image[r*WIDTH+c])
        arrays.append(block)

for block in arrays: print(block)

[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12]
[3, 4, 8, 9, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22]
[18, 19, 23, 24]
```

The trick is to stride through the image horizontally and vertically to go from one top-left corner of the window to the next.  Then build the blocks from these coordinates without exceeding the image dimensions

Alternatively you can pre-allocate the array of arrays and just run through the image to feed data into it:

```
hCount = (WIDTH-1) // windowSize + 1
vCount = (HEIGHT-1) // windowSize + 1
arrays = [ list() for _ in range(hCount*vCount) ]
for i in range(HEIGHT*WIDTH):
    b   = i // WIDTH // windowSize * hCount + i % WIDTH // windowSize
    arrays[b].append(image[i])
```

Comment: This looks very promising. However, the image is actually a flattened array as I have described in the question. This means `image = image.flatten()` and `image[r][c]` is not valid

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that part.  Fixed it now.

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you!